# Form input tab broken after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, sweetalert

I have a form for the registration of a user and is handled by an AJAX request.
When the AJAX request is finished, SweetAlert shows an update to the user with what happened, but when I've closed it and click back in a form field, the tab-key on the keyboard no longer does anything.

The settimeout is added so I can what the first swal is showing so I can "simulate" a slow internet connection.

```
<div class="box box-info">
    <div class="box-body">
        <form id="db-test">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" id="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class="pull-right btn btn-info" id="register"><b>register</b></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {

        $('#register').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var credentials = {
                username: $('#user').val(),
                password: $('#pass').val()
            }

            swal({
                title: 'Working on your registration',
                text: 'Give me a bit...<br/><br/><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>',
                html: true,
                showConfirmButton: false
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../register',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {'X-api': 'application/json'},
                    data: credentials
                })
                    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        swal({
                            title: 'Result',
                            text: '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + '</pre>',
                            html: true
                        })
                    });
            }, 1000);
        })
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging around, it seems it was a problem with `SweetAlert`.
There has been an issue open for quite a while now that describes the problem. https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/391

For now, it seems I need to do it like this (notice the `window.onkeydown` and `window.onfocus`:

```
swal({
    title: 'Working on your registration',
    text: 'Give me a bit...<br/><br/><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>',
    html: true,
    showConfirmButton: false
});
$.ajax({
    url: '../register',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'X-api': 'application/json'},
    data: credentials
})
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        window.onkeydown = window.onfocus = null; // This line is the solution
        swal({
            title: 'Result',
            text: '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + '</pre>',
            html: true
        })
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for sharing bud!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

You need to close your first `swal` properly. You are leaving it open. Set a `timer: 1000` on your first `swal` instead of using the `setTimeout` on the second. It's not needed.

```
swal({
    title: 'Working on your registration',
    text: 'Give me a bit...<br/><br/><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>',
    html: true,
    timer: 1000,
    showConfirmButton: false
});
```

On your AJAX call there's no need to use `.done`, just use `success` and then close your last `swal` on confirm `closeOnConfirm: true`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../register',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'X-api': 'application/json'},
    data: credentials,
    success: function (data) {
        swal({
            title: 'Result',
            text: '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + '</pre>',
            html: true,
            closeOnConfirm: true
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: First: The setTimeout is not important, read the question. Second: The doc and all examples on the jQuery.ajax() page show .done, not .success. Third: closeOnConfirm is not the solution, sorry.